# UISearchController extra unexpected UIView in hierarchy

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uisearchcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

I have problem with UISearchController. It is adding one extra View as direct child of its View. It has `isAccessibilityElement = true` and description "Double-tap to dismiss", this blocks all Appium automatic testing. I can't figure out why, where and how it is added.

Someone know when and why this view is added and how to remove it? I have tried to set its `isAccessibilityElement = false` form code but somehow it is set back to `true` in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who has this issue. It's caused by the default behaviour Apple have given the `UISearchController` where the `searchResultsController` is initially hidden until the `UISearchBar` has text.

We had old code in the searchResultsController to unhide itself `view.isHidden = false` which fought this default logic.

The fix was to remove this and instead set `searchController.showsSearchResultsController = true` which shows the results always and doesn't add the double tap to dismiss view.